# About function that maps no perfect to perfect.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a function such that $f[P]$ is countable where $P\subset\Bbb R$ is a perfect set, closed set with no isolated point. It is well known that the cardinality of perfect is a continuum and each perfect can be partitioned into a continuum of many pairwise disjoint perfect sets. With these facts in mind,

> -**Claim:** Fix a nonempty perfect set $K\subset\Bbb R$,  then there exists a nonempty perfect  $Q\subset K$ such that no perfect set can be mapped by $f$ into $Q$, that is, there is no nonempty perfect  $P\subset\Bbb R$ such that $f[P]\subset Q.$

Pick a perfect set $P\subset \Bbb R,$ by our assumption $f[P]$ is countable. So, there exists a perfect set $Q\subset K$ such that $Q=K\setminus f[P].$ So, $Q\cap f[P]=\emptyset.$ I do not think that will be enough to prove the claim. Is that right? Do I need to show $$Q\cap\bigcup_{P\in\mathcal P} f[P]=\emptyset,$$ where $\mathcal P$ are a family of all perfect subsets of $\Bbb R$?  If so, our assumption would not be enough to ensure that.

Any hint will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Let $f$ a constant and let $P=\emptyset$, then for any perfect set $K$, $f[P]\subset K$.

Comment: @Chris, $P$ supposed to be a nonempty set. I fixed.